# Jquery navigation tabs dropdown using child()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble creating a tab navigation menu. When I hover a navigation item I want to drop down a list with sub-links. I'm using the jquery `child()` function to display the sub-links of the tab I hover.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GeKv2/5/

When you hover a sub-link it appears to add a class `active` to it. What am I doing wrong here?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('ul.user_menu li').hover(function() {
    //show active tab
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("ul", $(this)).show();
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $("ul", $(this)).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the same effect using only CSS and the :hover selector.

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/xfBcn/1/

Comment: Wow thanks! +1. So I guess `display: block !important;` is making this possible